# Change SignIn default text

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I need to change the default text spoken to the user when prompted to SignIn. There is no easy configuration in the flow and I have found in [Calling the Helper](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/helpers#calling_the_helper_4) that no parameter is passed to the SignIn constructor. But, in the [Implementation guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#nodejs) there is a parameter: 'To get your account details', which does not appear in the [Dialogflow tab](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#json).

In the [Conversation playground](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/conversation-api-playground) the parameter exists as "optContext" but that does not work either. 
I am not using the libraries but I provide a fulfillment webhook for which I use only the JSON definitions.

Any advice on the subject? Should I forget about this and use a canvas? Canvas would work for this (I never used it)?

Thank you in advance

I acknowledge that this question is similar to others but their answers are rather old and sdk oriented.

Comment: What do you mean by the optContext parameter doesn't work? You can use this to add an introduction at the beginning of the text to explain why you want your user to sign-in. Is this not working at all?

Comment: I found out that the Simulator does not show it, it only shows the default full text, at least for me. But it works on a smartphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Dialogflow, and your fulfillment is sending back JSON without using one of the typical libraries, you need to make sure this is included in `payload.google` section of the response. Specifically, this will be a `systemIntent` object that contains the specific values relevant to Sign In.

It might look something like this, where the only part you change is the part labeled "YOUR TEXT GOES HERE". All the other values should be exactly as shown.

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValueSpec",
          "optContext": "YOUR TEXT GOES HERE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'm accepting this answer as the right one. Just a hint to anyone with this issue: my response looks like this:
``{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
     ...,
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValueSpec",
          "optContext": "MY TEXT GOES HERE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}``

The Simulator does not show the optContext text, but a smartphone shows it correctly, a little bug in the simulator maybe?